# react-native cookie auth not working on Android

Tags: android, react-native

My server returns a accesstoken and refreshtoken, I've setup iOS to correctly authenticate users using cookies (I do this by using `credentials: 'include'`). However when I try to run the Android version of my app, it won't persist any cookies and when I refresh the emulator, the backend server will return an error code causing my app to be logged out (the error code is being returned because it does not pass the cookies up!).

I had a look around to see what was up and I've came to the conclusion that it's not supported on the current version of react-native (0.59)? (check the link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21795)

Are there any workarounds for this? I heard rumours that this will be fixed in RN  0.60, but there is no release date set for this yet so I'll need to find my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes cookies authentication is currently not in stable state in react native,for android device.
for more details you can go with this link.

**https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network**